# cannot declare variable 't' to be of abstract type 'AddSalariedEmployee'

Tags: c++, build, constructor, abstract-class

I have a problem with compile in C++. Please help me!

Test.cpp

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../PayRoll/AddSalariedEmployee.h"
#include "../PayRoll/Employee.h"

class GregorianCalendar;

class PayrollTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    virtual void TearDown() {
    }
    virtual void SetUp() {
    }

public:
    PayrollTest() : Test() {
        int emId = 1;
        AddSalariedEmployee t(emId, "Bod", "Home", 1000.00);
        t.Execute();

    }
    GregorianCalendar* gregorian_calendar;
};


TEST(PayrollTest, check_name_employee) {
    Employee* e = GpayrollDatabase.GetEmployee(1);
    EXPECT_EQ("Bob", e->GetName());
}
```

AddSalariedEmployee.h

I think problem in this file

```
//
// Created by lngo9 on 11/24/2017.
//

#ifndef PAYROLL_ADDSALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H
#define PAYROLL_ADDSALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H

#include "AddEmployeeTransaction.h"

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class AddSalariedEmployee : public AddEmployeeTransaction {
    public:
        virtual ~AddSalariedEmployee();
        AddSalariedEmployee(int empid, string name, string address, double salary);
        PaymentClassification* GetClassification() const;
        PaymentSchedule* GetSchedule() const;

    private:
        double itsSalary;

};


#endif //PAYROLL_ADDSALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H
```

AddSalariedEmployee.cpp

```
//
// Created by lngo9 on 11/24/2017.
//

#include "AddSalariedEmployee.h"
#include "SalariedClassification.h"
#include "MonthlySchedule.h"

AddSalariedEmployee::~AddSalariedEmployee() {
}

AddSalariedEmployee::
AddSalariedEmployee(int empid, string name, string address, double salary)
        : AddEmployeeTransaction(empid, name, address)
        , itsSalary(salary){}

PaymentClassification*
AddSalariedEmployee::GetClassification() const {
    return new SalariedClassification(itsSalary);
}

PaymentSchedule* AddSalariedEmployee::GetSchedule() const {
    return new MonthlySchedule();
}
```

AddEmployeeTransaction.h

```
//
// Created by lngo9 on 11/24/2017.
//

#ifndef PAYROLL_ADDEMPLOYEETRANSACTION_H
#define PAYROLL_ADDEMPLOYEETRANSACTION_H

#include "Transaction.h"
#include "PayrollDatabase.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class PaymentClassification;
class PaymentSchedule;

extern PayrollDatabase GpayrollDatabase;

class AddEmployeeTransaction : public Transaction {
    public:
        virtual ~AddEmployeeTransaction();
        AddEmployeeTransaction(int empid, string name, string address);
        virtual PaymentClassification* GetClassification() const = 0;
        virtual PaymentSchedule* GetSchedule() const = 0;
        virtual void Execute() = 0;

    private:
        int itsEmpid;
        string itsName;
        string itsAddress;

};


#endif //PAYROLL_ADDEMPLOYEETRANSACTION_H
```

AddEmployeeTransaction.cpp

```
//
// Created by lngo9 on 11/24/2017.
//

#include "AddEmployeeTransaction.h"
#include "HoldMethod.h"
#include "Employee.h"

class PaymentMethod;
class PaymentSchedule;
class PaymentClassification;



AddEmployeeTransaction::~AddEmployeeTransaction() {
}

AddEmployeeTransaction::
AddEmployeeTransaction(int empid, string name, string address)
        : itsEmpid(empid)
        , itsName(name)
        , itsAddress(address){}

PaymentClassification* AddEmployeeTransaction::GetClassification() const {}

PaymentSchedule* AddEmployeeTransaction::GetSchedule() const {}

void AddEmployeeTransaction::Execute() {
    PaymentClassification* pc = GetClassification();
    PaymentSchedule* ps = GetSchedule();
    PaymentMethod* pm = new HoldMethod();
    Employee* e = new Employee(itsEmpid, itsName, itsAddress);
    e->SetClassification(pc);
    e->SetSchedule(ps);
    e->SetMethod(pm);
    GpayrollDatabase.AddEmployee(itsEmpid, e);

}
```

Transaction.h

```
//
// Created by lngo9 on 11/24/2017.
//

#ifndef PAYROLL_TRANSACTION_H
#define PAYROLL_TRANSACTION_H


class Transaction {
    public:
        virtual void Execute();
};


#endif //PAYROLL_TRANSACTION_H
```

When building i got the error:
 error: cannot declare variable 't' to be of abstract type 'AddSalariedEmployee'
         AddSalariedEmployee t(emId, "Bod", "Home", 1000.00);

Please help me! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

`AddSalariedEmployee` is  a child of `AddEmployeeTransaction`, which is an abstract class (you are using `= 0` for the body of some methods).
As those methods are not defined in the dervied class, the derived class is still abstract, and cannot be instantiated.

You need to define (implement) all abstract methods (even if you give them only an empty body `{}`), to be able to instantiate the child class.